# Sentence structure for "I have been ~ for X days"

Tags: syntax

I'm trying to say something along the lines of "I have been studying Japanese for 12 days". So far my research has led me to this attempt:

> わたしはじゅうににちにほんごをべんきょうしています。
>   watashi wa juuni nichi nihingo o benkyou shite imasu.

I suppose my question is whether this is a valid sentence, and if not, how would I phrase this so that it makes sense?

Comment: Is there anything in particular that makes you uncomfortable with your translation attempt?

Comment: @ajsmart It's not that I felt uncomfortable per se, just that I wasn't confident with the way I'd structured the sentence, but I get it now. Also, I was unsure whether or not I needed a particle after the duration part.

Answer (score 1):

(私{わたし}は)１２日間{にちかん}、日本語{にほんご}を勉強{べんきょう}しています。
(watashi wa) juu-ni nichi kan, nihongo wo benkyou shite imasu.

You don't need to add 私/僕/俺 if it's already understood from context that you are talking about yourself. Apparently it can seem obnoxious.

Numbers are often written as the actual numbers.

If you are just starting, I really recommend you check out Misa's lessons on YouTube! Here is her beginner [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUymRdqBglo&list=PLd5-Wp_4tLqZor0fbsXtP7t6npWeE-2IU). She does videos up to N3. Watching her made some things click for me the way reading about them didn't.

Comment: Since the OP is a beginner I added furigana to your answer (see the edit for how to do it).  To make this a good answer I recommend you say a little about why you added 間, since this isn't in the OP's original sentence, so they probably aren't aware of its function..

Comment: From what I understand, 間 (kan) acts as a counter of sorts, right? I definitely remember seeing it somewhere, but I just couldn't figure out when and when not to use it. Just so I know, "勉強" has to be connected to "日本ご" using "を" because that noun is what's being acted on by the verb, correct?

Comment: @KyleJones Your description of を is correct. 間 adds a meaning of duration. It is optional with some counters. See if this page helps: https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/japanese-numbers-durations.html

Comment: @user3856370 I see. Thanks for the help!